# how to run a bash script in background automatically?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, rm

I need to write a bash script that automatically deletes temp files, and runs in the background each day.

```
#!/bin/bash  
while true;  
do      
    rm  /home/c/temp/*
    sleep 24h
done
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Take a look at cron / crontab for this sort of thing .. or maybe a cron.daily file.  : http://serverfault.com/questions/135906/when-does-cron-daily-run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write a shell script

```
rm /home/c/temp/*
```

and add a line in the crontab

```
crontab -e
```

add the line

```
0 12 * * * path/to/script
```

It will execute you script every day at midday.

Comment: You would probably want to recommend removal of the unnecessary single-quotes around `temp`, but that's just a style issue...

Comment: Yes a just copy paste the line.